# Does hibernate lucene search provide SQL like analyzer

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I need to customized one of entity fields to be like sql liked search.

Answer (score 0):

You can accurately control the matching rules when you consider that you can affect both the shape your index has, and the kind of queries you throw at it.

A simple solution to your question is to use

```
@Field(analyze=Analyze.NO)
```

to disable the analysis of the field. This will take the String "as is" without any processing and index it like it was a special keyword.
This means it won't be tokenized (for example it won't be split on whitespaces) nor be otherwise processed (for example not made all lowercase).

At query time you then have to take care to also not process the keywords you're looking for. This is typically done with a `org.apache.lucene.index.Term`.

Finally, you can create a `org.apache.lucene.search.TermQuery` if you're looking for an exact match, or a `org.apache.lucene.search.PrefixQuery`, which takes a `Term` as parameter and will match all indexed fields which begin (prefix) matching your term, so this would be like " LIKE 'word%' ".

You have more flexibility if instead of disabling the Analyzer you create a custom one. For example if you need a "case-insensitive Like" you can define an Analyzer which doesn't split your input but does lowercase it, and so on..